# передача данных из json на страницу

Tags: javascript, json

у меня есть такой json файл

```
"{\"book_0\": {\"title\": \"Das Parfum: Die Geschichte Eines Morders\", \"author\": \"Patrick Suskind\", \"image\": \"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/3257228007.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg\", \"description\": \"Ein rares Meisterwerk zeitgen\\u00f6ssischer Prosa, eine dicht gesponnene, psychologisch raffiniert umgesetzte Erz\\u00e4hlung, die an die fr\\u00fchen St\\u00fccke von Patricia Highsmith erinnert, in ihrer Kunstfertigkeit aber an die Novellistik gro\\u00dfer europ\\u00e4ischer Erz\\u00e4hltradition ankn\\u00fcpft.\"}, \"book_1\": {\"title\": \"Sullivan's Woman (Silhouette Single Title)\", \"author\": \"Nora Roberts\", \"image\": \"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0373218966.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg\", \"description\": \"Sullivan's Woman by Nora Roberts released on Jul 25, 2003 is available now for purchase.\"},
```

это лишь часть, там книг куда больше

есть такой html код

```
<!-- Book -->
    <div id="book" class="book">
        <!-- Paper 1 -->
        <div id="p1" class="paper">
            <div class="front">
                <div id="f1" class="front-content">



                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div id="b1" class="back-content">
                    <!--<div id="output1"></div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Paper 2 -->
        <div id="p2" class="paper">
            <div class="front">
                <div id="f2" class="front-content">
                    <!--<div id="output2"></div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div id="b2" class="back-content">
                    <!--<div id="output3"></div>-->

                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

   <!-- Paper 3 -->
        <div id="p3" class="paper">
            <div class="front">
                <div id="f3" class="front-content">
                    <!--<div id="output4"></div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div id="b3" class="back-content">
                    <!--<div id="output5"></div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Paper 4 -->
<div id="p4" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
        <div id="f4" class="front-content">
            <!--<div id="output6"></div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <div id="b4" class="back-content">
           <!--<div id="output7"></div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Paper 5 -->
<div id="p5" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
        <div id="f5" class="front-content">
            <!--<div id="output8"></div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <div id="b5" class="back-content">
           <!--<div id="output9"></div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Paper 6 -->
<div id="p6" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
        <div id="f6" class="front-content">
            <!--<div id="output10"></div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <div id="b6" class="back-content">
            <h1>Back 6</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>





    <!-- Next Button -->
    <button id="next-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </button>
```

есть такой js файл, который как раз и должен выводит данные из этого json файла на экран

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "get_books/", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var books = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // Loop through each book
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(books).length; i++) {
      var bookKey = "book_" + i;
      var book = books[bookKey];

      // Check if the book object and its properties exist
      if (book && book.title && book.author && book.description && book.image) {
        // Create HTML elements for front and back content
        var frontContent = document.createElement("div");
        frontContent.innerHTML = "<h1>" + book.title + "</h1><p>" + book.author + "</p>";

        var backContent = document.createElement("div");
        backContent.innerHTML = "<p>" + book.description + "</p><img src='" + book.image + "' alt='" + book.title + "'>";

        // Append front and back content to corresponding divs
        document.getElementById("f" + (i + 1)).appendChild(frontContent);
        document.getElementById("b" + (i + 1)).appendChild(backContent);
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid book data for " + bookKey);
      }
    }
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

проблема в том, что он отказывается видеть характеристики каждой книги и если в каких-то попытках у меня и выводило что-либо, то лишь undefined.

Помогите разобраться с тем, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

> Помогите разобраться с тем, как это сделать

Так вроде все работает...

```js
const str = "{\"book_0\": {\"title\": \"Das Parfum: Die Geschichte Eines Morders\", \"author\": \"Patrick Suskind\", \"image\": \"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/3257228007.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg\", \"description\": \"Ein rares Meisterwerk zeitgen\\u00f6ssischer Prosa, eine dicht gesponnene, psychologisch raffiniert umgesetzte Erz\\u00e4hlung, die an die fr\\u00fchen St\\u00fccke von Patricia Highsmith erinnert, in ihrer Kunstfertigkeit aber an die Novellistik gro\\u00dfer europ\\u00e4ischer Erz\\u00e4hltradition ankn\\u00fcpft.\"}, \"book_1\": {\"title\": \"Sullivan's Woman (Silhouette Single Title)\", \"author\": \"Nora Roberts\", \"image\": \"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0373218966.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg\", \"description\": \"Sullivan's Woman by Nora Roberts released on Jul 25, 2003 is available now for purchase.\"}}"

const books = JSON.parse(str)
Object.keys(books).forEach((k, i) => {
      var book = books[k];

      // Check if the book object and its properties exist
      if (book && book.title && book.author && book.description && book.image) {
        // Create HTML elements for front and back content
        var frontContent = document.createElement("div");
        frontContent.innerHTML = "<h1>" + book.title + "</h1><p>" + book.author + "</p>";

        var backContent = document.createElement("div");
        backContent.innerHTML = "<p>" + book.description + "</p><img src='" + book.image + "' alt='" + book.title + "'>";

        // Append front and back content to corresponding divs
        document.getElementById("f" + (i + 1)).appendChild(frontContent);
        document.getElementById("b" + (i + 1)).appendChild(backContent);
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid book data for " + bookKey);
      }
})
```

```html
<!-- Book -->
<div id="book" class="book">
  <!-- Paper 1 -->
  <div id="p1" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f1" class="front-content">



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b1" class="back-content">
        <!--<div id="output1"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Paper 2 -->
  <div id="p2" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f2" class="front-content">
        <!--<div id="output2"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b2" class="back-content">
        <!--<div id="output3"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Paper 3 -->
  <div id="p3" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f3" class="front-content">
        <!--<div id="output4"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b3" class="back-content">
        <!--<div id="output5"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Paper 4 -->
  <div id="p4" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f4" class="front-content">
        <!--<div id="output6"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b4" class="back-content">
        <!--<div id="output7"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Paper 5 -->
  <div id="p5" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f5" class="front-content">
        <!--<div id="output8"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b5" class="back-content">
        <!--<div id="output9"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Paper 6 -->
  <div id="p6" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f6" class="front-content">
        <!--<div id="output10"></div>-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b6" class="back-content">
        <h1>Back 6</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: здравствуй! К сожалению по url "get_books/" этот json файл создается на беке и он постоянно разный. он состоит лишь 10 книг, которые отдельным скриптом отбираются, и я не могу взять эти данные и вставить в код. Нужно, чтобы скрипт, как показано изначально через url get_books мог принят json файл и вывести его на экран по книге на страницу (страница в данном случае элемент дизайна проекта). При таком раскладе мне выдает ошибки, по типу "параметр title или author " не найден. Извините, если не четко сформулировал

Comment: @Mirael, вот когда "примешь" тот json - используй этот код.

Comment: Тогда назревает другой вопрос, вот я его принимаю с помощью json.parse в своем скрипте. Но как мне сделать, как у вас, чтобы эти данные можно было динамически "запихнуть" в const str, как вы показываете. Я немного не понимаю, где именно ошибка

Comment: @Mirael, так ты смотри что именно принимаешь... Может ты не с тем работаешь - https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest#tip-otveta